# Extrude faces of an icosphere from a python script

Tags: python, scripting

I have an array of values and I need to extrude each face - **faces[*i*]** - of an icosphere with the amount of ***arr[i]*** in the direction of it's normal.

I managed to extrude the face I have selected by hand and managed to get the list of all faces of the mesh, but can't find a way to combine these solutions.

Comment: Share what you have so far.

Comment: `list(bpy.context.object.data.polygons)` seems to give the faces. And `bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move('INVOKE_REGION_WIN', TRANSFORM_OT_translate={ "constraint_orientation": 'NORMAL', "value": (x, y, z)})` extrudes the face that is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces` takes a list of faces and extrudes them, leaving them in the original place with new joining geometry. If we take the `['faces']` part of the data returned by `extrude_discrete_faces` we have a list of faces that have been extruded, these are the 'original' faces only, not the extra joining faces.

For each of these extruded faces we take the face normal and multiply it by the distance you wish to move the face and use that in `bmesh.ops.translate` to position them where you want.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# sample set for cube
extrude_values = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data,face_normals=True)

extrude_faces = bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces(bm, faces=bm.faces)['faces']

for f_idx in range(len(extrude_faces)):
    dr = extrude_faces[f_idx].normal * extrude_values[f_idx]
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm, verts=extrude_faces[f_idx].verts, vec=dr)

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
obj.data.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by doing a LOT of analytic geometry and avoid bpy.ops as much as possible (because bpy.ops has cooties).  In fact, part of what you want I already did in my [spikify](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/spikify.html)  script  for the [azathoth boogie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAsPEG7EyBw) animation.

In my case I was interpolating between the triangle of the icosphere face and the degenerate tip of the spike.  Here's an excerpt:

```
def fab_layer(verts, base_indices, layer, max_layers, max_radius):

    vavg = average( [ verts[vi] for vi in base_indices])

    tip = vavg * max_radius / vavg.magnitude

    rval_vi = []

    for i in range(len(base_indices)):
        v0 = verts[base_indices[i]]
        v1 = (v0 * (max_layers-layer) + tip*layer ) / max_layers
        idx = len(verts)
        rval_vi.append(idx)
        verts.append(v1)

    return rval_vi
```

If you can mathematically decide what it means to "extrude" for **your** application (which will likely be different than mine) then you can come up with your own code.