# Python script won't shift face of simple cube

Tags: python

I'm making a simple script that adds a cube and moves it, and then I want to shift some of the faces, in order to change the cube's width height or depth. When I run it, the cube is created and moved, but altering de cube's dimensions gives an error:

convertViewVec: called in an invalid context

I'm using the code that's shown in the Info window when I select a face and drag it along one of the axes. I'm new to Blender and I can't figure out what's missing here..

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 6.04281, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, -5.22667), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 2.9328, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 1.03954, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
```

Edit - Solved it by creating a custom geometry, as shown here: [How to create a mesh programmatically, without bmesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh) (Pointed out by @poor)

The following code now creates a flat cube:

```
import bpy  

verts = [
(2.0, 1.0, -1.0), 
(2.0, 0.99, -1.0), 
(-1.0, 0.99, -1.0), 
(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0), 
(2.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
(2.0, 0.99, 1.0), 
(-1.0, 0.99, 1.0), 
(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)]

faces = [
(0, 1, 2, 3), 
(4, 7, 6, 5), 
(0, 4, 5, 1), 
(1, 5, 6, 2), 
(2, 6, 7, 3), 
(4, 0, 3, 7)]

mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("cube_mesh_data")  
mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)  
mesh_data.update()

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("My_Object", mesh_data)  

scene = bpy.context.scene    
scene.objects.link(obj)    
obj.select = True
```

Comment: I think [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23466/935) has the solution you are after.

Comment: Welcome dcvsu :) sambler's answer linked in the comment above should solves your issue, if not feel free to comment here. To position your object see this answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26852/python-move-object-on-local-axis/26854#26854 Anyway, Enjoy the site!

Comment: Hi thanks @poor. The other answer also adds new faces, and that's not what I want to do. In Blender (manually) I select a face and drag it along one of the axes, changing the cube's width height or depth. (Maybe 'extrude' isn't the right word here).

Comment: Ahh - You want to shift the faces, right? If yes, edit your question to reopen it. In general there a 3 possibilities: **create a custom geometry via python**, **shifting the selected faces** or **scale the object**. Number 2 could be expensive, because you have to create an algorithm to get the right face. For 1 see this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh.

Comment: I edited the question, but it's solved now; creating a custom geometry via python did the job. Thanks a lot @poor!

Comment: Voted to reopen it, maybe you want to answer your own question :)